# How to check if a association is not loaded?

Tags: ecto

What function can I use to check if a association is already loaded?
It would be nice to check if a association is loaded instead of trying to use it and getting `Ecto.Association.NotLoaded` error.

Answer (score 28):

You can use `assoc_loaded?`

Reference:
https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#assoc_loaded?/1

Comment: This is the way

Answer (score 6):

Not sure if there's a built-in function to check for this, but you could write your own like this:

```
defmodule PreloadCheck do
  def is_preloaded(model, assoc) do
    case Map.get(model, assoc) do
      %Ecto.Association.NotLoaded{} -> false
      _ -> true
    end
  end
end
```

Here `assoc` would be the atom representing your association name.

Using pattern matching in `case` allows you to check if your association is loaded or if it's still returning a `Ecto.Association.NotLoaded` struct.

Comment: Thanks. I end up writing a function that simple check if the association is a list and count that as loaded.
I'm still hoping there is something of builtin function that does this.

Comment: Yeah, you can use `Ecto.assoc_loaded?` ;) it will return a bool for loaded or not. I'm just not sure exactly how long the function is available, at least for version 2.1.4 is available.

Comment: Where this function will be written and how will affect the model? if you can explain that will be greate

Comment: See the Hex docs essentially Ecto.association_loaded?(model.association) which returns a boolean https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html#assoc_loaded?/1